# Javascript displaying a var in code

Tags: javascript, html

I want the value of some vars to be shown in the string.

```
 function test()
 {
 var first = document.getElementById('first').value; //value ==hello
 var second = document.getElementById("second").value; //value == bye
 var third = document.getElementById("third").value;   //value == crazy
 var forth = document.getElementById("forth").value;    // value == night


 var myString = " \
 <script> \
 var firstValue = "\" + first + \""; \
 var secondValue = "\" + second + \""; \
 var thirdValue = "\" +third + \""; \
 var forthValue = "\" +forth + \""; \
 <\/script> ";
```

I want the string to display:

```
 <script> 
 var firstValue = " hello "; 
 var secondValue = "  bye "; 
 var thirdValue = " crazy "; 
 var forthValue = " night "; 
 </script> ";
```

Comment: You're question is not clear. What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your question that are causing answerers to have to guess how to help you.  Could you share a program that doesn't have any syntax errors with us, perhaps in the form of a [Minimum Complete Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

variables names in javascript can't start with a number.

So change your variable names.

```
var name1  = document.getElementById('1').value;
```

should be better.

Answer (score 0):

To convert any value to string just concatinate value with an empty string like - `""+document.getElementById('1').value`

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PR3u/2/)

Comment: function myFunction()
{
var amen1 = document.getElementById("amen1").value;
alert(amen1.toString().split(" "));
}. This will also work

Comment: @VinayakPingale i know yes it will work.He already mentioned that in his question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem just boils down to wrong escaping in the string, which you should recognise simply by code highlighting:

```
 var myString = " \
 <script> \
 var firstValue = \"" + first + "\"; \
 var secondValue = \"" + second + "\"; \
 var thirdValue = \"" +third + "\"; \
 var forthValue = \"" +forth + "\"; \
 <\/script> ";
```

You always escape the characters you want to keep in your string and not those, which have a syntactical meaning in the definition!